# iOS: Image scaling using auto layout in Storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

I have a launch screen with a image at bottom right corner. Constraints are as follows:

1. Width: Width of `UIImageView` must be one fourth of superview.
2. Left: Left margin is zero with superview
3. Bottom: Bottom margin is zero with superview

and also mode for `imageview` is set to `Aspect Fit`.

What should be the height constraint, so that the `image` in the `UIImageView` is bottom aligned for all devices and all orientations.

[image: 6S Plus landscape]

[image: 6s Plus portrait]

In the screenshots, the `image` is not bottom aligned, although the `imageview` is.

[image]

Comment: Please show your constraints?

Comment: I have added another image, that shows the image view is bottom right aligned by setting different background colour. And there is no height constraint. Image view is taking the initial height as the height of Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution to my problem is `Aspect Ratio` constraint, with all the constraints in question.